# How to perform a Django test with a request.post?

Tags: python, django, django-tests

I'm using Django 1.8 and Python 3.5.

I have a view method I would love to test. I am supplying the `self.client.get` method with the data but it fails to validate the form. what am I doing wrong?

This is the view method:

```
def saveNewDriverInfo(request):
    if  request.user.is_authenticated():
        form = DriverForm(request.POST)  
        if  form.is_valid():
            new_Driver = form.save()
            carid = form.cleaned_data['carID']
            Car = get_object_or_404(Car, pk=carid)
            return redirect('carmanager:carDetails', carID=carid
        else:
            return HttpResponse("something went wong some where! yes i said wong!")
```

This is the test method:

```
 def test_saveNewDriverInfo(self):
            self.client.login(username="testuser",password="testuser321")
response= self.client.get(reverse('carmanager:saveNewDriverInfo'),data={'form':{'carID':'1034567','Driver_Last_Name':'daddy','Driver_First_Name':'daddy','Driver_Middle_Initial':'K','entered_by':'king'}})
            #self.assertRedirects(response, expected_url, status_code, target_status_code, host, msg_prefix, fetch_redirect_response)
         
            self.assertNotContains(response, 'something went wrong' ,200)
```

Also, note that this test works because it gets the response. But the line that is commented out is what I want to use.

However, I cant seem to feed the information to the DriverForm. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use `self.client.post(url, data)` in your test, since your view is looking for the POST data (`request.POST`) and not for `request.GET`.

I'd also suggest to refactor your view to match the template given here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#the-view

I am a little confused by the way your test passes data to `self.client.get`. Assuming your form has the fields `carID`, `Driver_Last_Name`, etc, the call to `self.client.get` should look like `self.client.get(url, data={'carID': <id>, 'Driver_Last_Name': <driver_last_name>, ...})`. The `'form'` key should not be needed. The same goes for `self.client.post`. See also here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get